# Removing the white space around plots when using customized FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, ticks

I'm using the `CustomTicks` package, which is part of the `LevelScheme` package, for styling the `FrameTicks` in my plots. On some sides of the plot frame, I want to have `FrameTicks` without tick labels. The problem is that I get extra white space in the place where the tick labels used to be. (Here, I have produced the plots with `LightGray` background in order to highlight the cropping problem.)

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"]

plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1},
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 1, ShowTickLabels -> False],LinTicks[0, 1]},
  Background -> LightGray
]
```

[image: Plot with unwanted white space]

I think that the problem arises because the nonlabeled ticks are created as `""`, as can be seen in `FullForm[plot]`. How can I achieve a result similar to `Plot[x,{x,0,1},Frame->True]`, i.e., a tight cropping of the plot around its frame (see below) with customized `FrameTicks`?

I do not want to rasterize my plot; thus, `ImageCrop` is not an option.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1},
  Frame -> True,
  Background -> LightGray
]
```

[image: Correct cropping but with default <code>FrameTicks</code>]

Comment: I didn't try it with this package, but does ImagePadding work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect with the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePadding.html) option. The syntax is `ImagePadding-> {{left,right},{bottom,top}}`.

This does not require you to rasterize the graphic. It might mean that you have to work out the appropriate whitespace on the sides that DO have tick labels, though.

I do not have `CustomTicks` installed but here is a simple function that tries to work out how much space you need on the bottom and left sides, instead of having to guess.

```
maxLabelSpace[labels_?VectorQ, type_String, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[{Style}]] := 
 With[{dim = Switch[type, "Horizontal", 1, "Vertical", 2, _, 1]}, 
  Max[ImageDimensions[#][[dim]] & /@ (Rasterize /@ (Style[ToString@#, 
          Sequence @@ {opts}] & /@ labels))]]
```

You can then do:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> 12, 
 ImagePadding -> {{maxLabelSpace[{-0.5, 0.5, 1}, "Horizontal", 
  FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12], 1}, {maxLabelSpace[Range[4], "Vertical",    
  FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12], 1}}]
```

[image]

Notice that I've set the `ImagePadding` on the non-labeled sides to be 1, not 0. This avoids the frame being cut off.

Exercises for the reader include extending the `maxLabelSpace` function to add a pixel or two of whitespace to the `ImagePadding`, if that's what you want, via another parameter. You could also write a custom plotting function that automatically captures ticks and `OptionValue[FrameStyle]` to pass to `maxLabelSpace`.